# Plotly python subplots

Tags: python, plot, plotly

I’m trying to make subplots with these two plots and cannot make it work. I need the output to be a “div” with the two plots stacked vertically as subplots.  Normally I would just use Matplotlib -- but I need the 3D ribbon plot from Plotly.

Like this:

plot 1

plot 2

Thank you for your help!

Eric

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import plotly.offline as offline
from plotly import tools
import numpy as np

data0 = list(np.random.normal(-5,.5,25))
data1 = list(np.random.normal(-3.5,1,25))
data2 = list(np.random.normal(0,2,25))
data3 = list(np.random.normal(1,1,25))
data4 = list(np.random.normal(5,3,25))
data5 = list(np.random.normal(7,5,25))
index = list(range(0,len(data0),1))

spectra = [
index,
data0,
data1,
data2,
data3,
data4,
data5
]

spectra = np.transpose(spectra)

traces1 = []
y_raw = spectra[:, 0] # wavelength
sample_size = spectra.shape[1]-1
for i in range(1, sample_size):
z_raw = spectra[:, i]
x = []
y = []
z = []
ci = int(255/sample_size*i) # ci = “color index”
for j in range(0, len(z_raw)):
    z.append([z_raw[j], z_raw[j]])
    y.append([y_raw[j], y_raw[j]])
    x.append([i*2, i*2+1])
    traces1.append(dict(
    z=z,
    x=x,
    y=y,
    colorscale=[ [i, 'rgb(100,%d,255)'%ci] for i in np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1)],
    showscale = False,
    showlegend = True,
    type='surface',
))

# First subplot
fig1 = {'data':traces1, 'layout':{'title':'Ribbon Plot'}}
div1 = offline.plot(fig1, filename='Distplot with Multiple Datasets',show_link=False, include_plotlyjs=False, output_type='div')

traces2 = [data0, data1, data2, data3, data4, data5]

group_labels = ['a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5']
# Second subplot

fig2 = ff.create_distplot(traces2, group_labels, bin_size=.2)
div2 = offline.plot(fig2, filename='Distplot with Multiple Datasets', show_link=False, include_plotlyjs=False, output_type='div')
```

Comment: plot 1 and 2 are produced via the 'fig1', 'fig2' commands along with the 'div1' and 'div2' commands.

Comment: OK, one more thing:  you are using  ‘ and ’ instead of  ' like ‘Blackbody’ replace by 'Blackbody',  also could you please fix indentation problems in your code?

Comment: Fixed intents and removed 'commented out' code for clarity.

Comment: there are still indentation issues as well as  ‘ and ’ .  On the other hand, which layout you would like?  https://plot.ly/python/subplots/  .. maybe Stacked Subplots?

Comment: Yes, stacked subplots.  I don't know what you mean by ' and '.

Comment: I meant replace all occurrences of these characters:  `‘` and `’`  by:  `'` in your code like : `‘rgb` by `'rgb`  or `‘data’` by `'data'` or  ‘`a0’, ‘a1’, ‘a2’, ‘a3’, ‘a4’, ‘a5’` by `'a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User Empet from Plotly posted a solution to my question here:  https://plot.ly/~empet/14824

I added some custom coloring to make the plots look better together.

Very helpful!  Thank you Empet!

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline as offline
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import plotly.offline as offline
from plotly import tools
import numpy as np

fig = tools.make_subplots(specs=[[{'is_3d': True}], [{'is_3d':False}], [{'is_3d':False}]], vertical_spacing=0.005, rows=3, cols=1)

data0 = list(np.random.normal(-5,.5,25))
data1 = list(np.random.normal(-3.5,1,25))
data2 = list(np.random.normal(0,2,25))
data3 = list(np.random.normal(1,1,25))
data4 = list(np.random.normal(5,3,25))
data5 = list(np.random.normal(7,5,25))
index = list(range(0,len(data0),1))

spectra = [
    index,
    data0,
    data1,
    data2,
    data3,
    data4,
    data5
]

spectra = np.transpose(spectra)

y_raw = spectra[:, 0] # wavelength
sample_size = spectra.shape[1]-1
for i in range(1, sample_size):
    z_raw = spectra[:, i]
    x = []
    y = []
    z = []
    ci = int(255/sample_size*i) # ci = “color index”
    for j in range(0, len(z_raw)):
        z.append([z_raw[j], z_raw[j]])
        y.append([y_raw[j], y_raw[j]])
        x.append([i*2, i*2+1])
    fig.append_trace(dict(
                z=z,
                x=x,
                y=y,
                colorscale=[ [i, 'rgb(100,{}, 255)'.format(ci)] for i in np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1)],
                showscale = False,
                showlegend = True,
                type='surface',
                ), 1, 1)


colors = ['rgb(100,000,255)', 'rgb(100,50,255)','rgb(100,100,255)','rgb(100,150,255)','rgb(100,200,255)','rgb(100,250,255)']

traces2 = [data0, data1, data2, data3, data4, data5]

group_labels = ['a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5']

# Second subplot
fig2 = ff.create_distplot(traces2, group_labels, bin_size=.2,colors =.  colors)

for mydata in fig2['data']:
    if mydata['yaxis']=='y1':
        fig.append_trace(mydata, 2, 1)
    else:
        fig.append_trace(mydata, 3, 1)

fig['layout']['scene1'].update(camera=dict(eye=dict(x=.25, y=.25, z=.25)))
fig['layout']['scene1']['domain'].update(y=[0.6, 1])

fig['layout']['yaxis2'].update(domain=[0, 0.1375])
fig['layout']['yaxis1'].update(domain=[0.1575, 0.55])
fig['layout']['xaxis2'].update(zeroline=False)#remove the line x=0 in the lower cell

fig['layout'].update(height=900, width=1000, autosize=True, legend=dict(x=1.1, y=0.40), barmode='overlay')

my_div = offline.plot(fig, filename='Distplot with Multiple Datasets', show_link=False, include_plotlyjs=False, output_type='div')

print(my_div)
```